# System name appearing as Domain name

Tags: networking, workgroup

There is a workgroup in my institution and I added all the needed systems to it. There is a server in it and a folder in the server is shared in the network, to share files between different systems. The shared location is accessible from all systems, except one.

Today a new system is added to the workgroup and I tried to access the shared folder in the server from the newly added system. Since it was for the first time, it asked for Username and Password. So I entered both and pressed Enter, but I was unable to access it.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the problem is not with Username and Password. You can see that under Username and Password Text fields it is written 'Domain:PRINCIPAL'. Actually PRINCIPAL is the name of the newly added system. I added this system to the workgroup already and I don't created any Domain till now. How this Domain is coming here ? How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: If you only knew that a domain-name can relate to the system-name too! :)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful How can I remove the domain name from there ?

Comment: You can't ,as it is necessary for verifying the credentials, your machine/system is getting recognised based on your SYSTEM's name, i.e., "PRINCIPAL" here. Also, that's not an issue, move on and forget about this.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I can't access the shared location from this machine. What should I do then ?